# How to get last n elements of a Treemap

Tags: java, treemap

I have a TreeMap, that looks like this:

```
 TreeMap<Instant, HashMap<Type, Double>>
```

The Instant values are representing hours of a day; for each passed hour a value is stored in my map.
Now I would like to get the last 24 elements (so the hours of the passed day) of this map. How could I do that?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`descendingMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap%28%29) call to get a view on the map which is basically in the reverse order, then take the first 24 entries from that (call `iterator` etc). ([Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) provides helpful methods for limiting an iterable etc.)

EDIT: For example, to get the last 24 elements (in reverse order, and using Guava) you could use:

```
List<HashMap<Type, Double>> lastValues = Lists.newArrayList
    (Iterables.limit(map.descendingMap().values(), 24));
```

Answer (score 4):

use [TreeMap.tailMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#tailMap%28java.lang.Object%29) for it.

Comment: Problem here is, that if i use tailMap(), I would need to know the exact element, where the tail should start... Because the map changes all the time this isn't really applicable.

Comment: @NikolausHartlieb i think you need to ensure that during your fetching the 24 elements, the map is not gonna be changed. (e.g. the fetch thread can only start before HH:55. )otherwise there is no way to get the correct elements for you. e.g. you fetch (either by tailMap or desendingMap) on 10:59:59.990. you have very high probability to have wrong dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a `SortedMap<LocalDate, SortedMap<Hours, Map<Type, Double>>>` so you can get the latest date from the outer `Map`.