# Extract last x value from a treep map using guava

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, guava, treemap

I have a TreeMap of Long and String and I have sorted it in reverse order of keys so that I can see latest timestamp at the top of the map. Bbelow is my code in which `clientHistory` will be sorted on keys in descending order.

```
Map<Long, String> clientHistory = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

for(...) {
    // ... some code
    clientHistory.put(data.getModifiedTime(), clientId);
}
```

Now for example, if `clientHistory` map has 500 elements in it. I want to extract last 400 clientId from that map into a List, basically first latest 100 client id I want to ignore.

I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588902/how-to-get-last-n-elements-of-a-treemap) and I tried out like this:

```
Map<Long, String> clientHistory = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

for(...) {
    // ... some code
    clientHistory.put(data.getModifiedTime(), clientId);
}

List<String> lastClientIdValues = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.limit(clientHistory.descendingMap().values(), clientHistory.size() - 100));
```

Th above line is giving me an error as `The method descendingMap() is undefined for the type Map<Long,String>`. What wrong I am doing?

Do I even need a TreeMap if I am using `descendingMap` feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need guava for this. You can do it as follows:

```
int size = yourMap.size();
List<String> leastRecent = new ArrayList<>(
    yourMap.values()).subList(size - 400, size);
```

This will return the least recent values from your map, according to the keys, since your map is already ordering its entries in descending order.

Comment: Or instead of sorting in descending order, if I keep it in ascending order, then I can use your first suggestion. Correct?

Comment: @user1950349 Correct. But in that case you'll have the entries ordered from least recent to most recent. Just try and see.